# How to check copy assignment operator in c++ in noexcept() function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, noexcept, declval

I try to check template class `T` in function `do_math()` on the possibility of throwing an exception in the copy assignment operator.

But the following code throws an error:

```cpp
template<class T>
void do_math()
    noexcept(noexcept(T(std::declval<T>())) && noexcept(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>()) && noexcept(std::declval<T>().operator = (std::declval<T>())) )
{

}
```

```
main.cpp:9:135: error: request for member ‘operator=’ in ‘std::declval<int>()’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
     noexcept(noexcept(T(std::declval<T>())) && noexcept(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<T>()) && noexcept(std::declval<T>().operator = (std::declval<T>())) )
                                                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Please help me to write the correct check.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to write this yourself. There is already a type trait for it in the standard library:

```
#include<type_traits>
```

and then

```
std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable<T>::value
```

gives you `true`/`false` and can be used in the `noexcept` specifier.

Similarly there is

```
std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value
```

to check whether non-throwing copy construction is possible.

Note however that if `T` is not a lvalue reference type, then `std::declval<T>` is a rvalue, not a lvalue. Therefore your current code is testing for *move* constructibility, not copy constructibility. (There are analogous type traits for these as well.)